# USB and charging port is not working after rooting

Tags: usb, charging

I have rooted my HTC Desire 620G with kingoroot. After rooting the phone is not getting charged while its switched on.

The phone can be charged by switched it off. Also the phone can not be connected with Laptop via USB, hence I am unable to unroot it again.

It seems like kingo has blocked the charging/USB port.battery is draining very fast. I have reset the phone but no luck. Can anyone help??

Comment: How did you *reset* the phone? Did you reboot? Or is this a factory reset, in which case your phone should no longer be rooted?

Comment: After factory reset still it showing rooted.I rooted it with Kningo root.After rooting one app named Kingo SuperUser has been installed in my phone which can not be removed even after factory reset. Now I have having two issue. 1.usb/charging port not working ,2.battery is draining very fast

Comment: Are you willing to flash stock ROM or a custom ROM in your phone? If yes, then install a custom Recovery in your device (it is rooted so you can flash the Recovery from inside the Android, no need for ADB/USB cable). Once done, find the stock/custom ROM recovery flashable zip for your device and flash it from the custom Recovery, and do a full wipe before it -- all the data, apps, that Kingo superuser, all these things would be gone, so do take **backup before proceeding**.

Comment: it sounds very complicated.I can not proceed with all these until get detailed information.looking in to it.